# Swift UIPageViewController & UIActivityIndicatorView

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

Is anyone aware of an issue with stopping a UIActivityIndicatorView (AI) / removing a UIView that has been added to a UIPageViewController?

I am showing the AI using:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    actInd.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 80, 80)
    actInd.center.x = self.view.center.x
    actInd.center.y = self.view.center.y - 40
    actInd.hidesWhenStopped = true
    actInd.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    actInd.alpha = 0.5
    actInd.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    actInd.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge
    self.view.addSubview(actInd)
    actInd.startAnimating()

    // This next line prints out the details of each subview on the page for testing purposes
    listSubviews(self.view)
```

I am also, for testing purposes, adding a blank UIView to the view using:

```
    aView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)
    aView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    self.view.addSubview(aView)
}
```

Then I send my Parse.com query using a delegate to advise the UIPageViewController (e.g. this view) when the data is ready. This is working fine and I have tested that the data returns correctly, and that the expected method is being called.

In this method I try to stop the UIActivityViewController & try to hide aView:

```
self.actInd.stopAnimating()
aView.removeFromSuperView()
```

This didn't work so I tried:

```
self.actInd.removeFromSuperView()
```

This didn't work either. So I then tried to search through the subviews on the current view using:

```
func populateBoards(boards: [Board]) {
    println(self.actInd) // PRINT LINE 1

    var subviews = self.view.subviews

    for v in subviews {

        if v.isKindOfClass(UIActivityIndicatorView) {
            println("YES, it is an activity view indicator \(v)") // PRINT LINE 2
            v.stopAnimating()
            v.removeFromSuperview()
        }

    }

    self.boards = boards
    println("Populated Boards!") // PRINT LINE 3
}
```

PRINT LINE 1 outputs: >

PRINT LINE 2 outputs: YES, it is an activity view indicator  >

PRINT LINE 3 outputs: "Populated boards!"

EDIT:

The UIPageViewController is setup with the following code (in case it helps):

```
func setupUIPageView() {

    self.pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle.Scroll, navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation.Horizontal, options: nil)
    self.pageViewController.delegate = self
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self

    var startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0) as ViewController
    var viewControllers:[ViewController] = [startVC]

    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)

    self.pageViewController.view.alpha = 0.0

    self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
    self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

}
```

Help! Thanks all in advance :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call all your UI related code on the main queue. Your Parse query is async and the completion block might be called on a different thread.

Wrap this call in this block:

```
NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
  self.actInd.stopAnimating()
}
```

Comment: Perfect, that worked thanks. I didn't realise that was even possible :D

Comment: You might be interested in this class: https://github.com/goktugyil/CozyLoadingActivity